# How to add custom folders to an exported Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: java, export, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse application which loads a file from a folder. When I export the project and run it, the folder is only compiled binary in a jar file. But I want to edit the file after the export and so I need it in the product directory and not inside a jar. 
The folder is checked in the build.properties which should be the right way but it still does not work.
Does anyone know where else to configure that the folder is exported as a real folder?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to install the plug-in in the "unpacked" form rather than in the "jar" form. This way the folders of the plug-in project in the Eclipse IDE, will also be "physical" folders when the plug-in is installed in an Eclipse framework.

This can be accomplished in a number of ways, whether the most portable currently seems to be to add the line `Eclipse-BundleShape: dir` to the `MANIFEST.MF` file. (Some tools - most notably Tycho - does not understand the alternatives.)

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked fine for me. Now it would be nice to select the files to put in "physical" folders. With your solution the complete plugin, in which's metadata the line is added, is exported as folder.

Comment: Within a plug-in, you specify the included files in `build.properties`. It is pretty easy to edit this file via the "build" page of the PDE editor.

Comment: Perfect! Now I understand the usage of the build.properties. I've had the wrong folders selected so that the classes were also exported in folders. Now it works and I have only Metadata in a folder and the classes in a jar.

Comment: krabbenmeister, are you saying that you can export some parts of the project in JAR format and others in folder/file format?? I use the same configuration, and everything gets exported as folder/file...

Answer (score 3):

You can export additional files via features, and these can be contributed as folders to the root. Look for rootfolders in the eclipse PDE documentation. You have to use some special entries in the build.properties of your feature, that can not be done via PDE ui.

Having said that, it is probably a bad idea to alter those files and the product directory. This will cause issues on most multi-user and modern operating systems. The changes should be stored with the data for the plugin/OSGI bundle that produces them. Consider this method: http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getDataFile(java.lang.String)

Comment: I want to export some files in folders (not jars), for example my log4j.xml, because then I can change the logging settings after the product export. It is more for maintenance than for productivity use.